# I have to click the cancel button twice before the click event fires

Tags: jquery

I have a modal popup form where the user can click cancel to exit the form. If the user has started entering data into the form, the user is asked if they want to confirm they want to exit without saving the changes.

What is happening is that I enter some data and when I click the cancel button, the _isModalDirty flag is set, but the button click event (ie $('.modal-cancel').click(function (){ ... });) is not fired. When I click the cancel button again, it is fired.
What do I need to change so that the button click event is fired first time?

```
$('.controls :input').change(function (){
    _isModalDirty = true;
});

$('.modal-cancel').click(function (){
    if (_isModalDirty) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel? You will lose your unsaved changes.')) {
            closeModalPopup();
        }
    } else {
        closeModalPopup();
    }
});

var closeModalPopup = function () {
    resetModalPopup();
    _isModalDirty = false;
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
}

var resetModalPopup = function() {
    $('.controls :input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.val('');
    });    
}
```

EDIT
And here is the html;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-quote-form">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Quote", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editQuoteForm", @class = "modalPopup" }))
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="EditQuoteQuoteId" name="QuoteId" />
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit Quote for Tender</legend>
            <p style="color: white;font-weight: bold;"><span id="EditCompany"></span></p>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="controls col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label label-default" for="Status">Status</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls col-md-2">
                        <select id="QuoteStatus">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="controls col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label label-default" for="Value">Value</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls col-md-2">
                        <input type="text" id="EditQuoteValue" name="maskValue" class="maskValue"
                            style="text-align: right; width: 160px;"
                            data-inputmask="'alias': 'numeric', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true, 'digits': 2, 'digitsOptional': false, 'prefix': '£ ', 'placeholder': '0'" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="editValue" class="editValue" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="controls col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label label-default" for="Comments">Comments</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls col-md-2" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <textarea id="EditComments" name="Comments" class="commentsTextarea"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning modal-cancel" value="Cancel" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

EDIT2

And the above form is fired from the following hyperlink in the main form;

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Tender Quotes</legend>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;" class="bootstrapLink">
            <a href="#edit-quote-form" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal">Add New Quote</a>
        </div>
        @grid.GetHtml()
    </fieldset>
```

EDIT3
This is the fiddle of it not working; http://jsfiddle.net/arame3333/mto9mt9v/7/

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle including your HTML code?

Comment: Where is the code for the cancel button?

Comment: is it an actual button or link? if so you may need to prevent the default action

Comment: html content also ...

Comment: Based on what you have so far I made this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mto9mt9v/ As you can see the click event does fire. So , as the other comments stated, please provide us with more information.

Comment: I have just posted the HTML. Apologies for not doing that originally.

Comment: What language is `@using (Html.BeginForm...`?

Comment: @j08691 ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: So this is the fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/arame3333/mto9mt9v/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. To be honest I do not understand why this is the answer and I do not understand why JsFiddle did not reproduce it.
However I just swapped the order of the functions and then it worked;

```
var _isModalDirty = false;

$('.modal-cancel').click(function () {
    if (_isModalDirty) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel? You will lose your unsaved changes.')) {
            closeModalPopup();
        }
    } else {
        closeModalPopup();
    }
});

$('.controls :input').change(function () {
    _isModalDirty = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the flag isn't functioning as intended.

```
 $('.controls :input').change(function (){
    _isModalDirty = true;
});
```

Instead of a change event, I would do a compare of original vs current at submit time.
So, first on modal create, store orig values:

```
var origdata=[];
 $('.controls :input').each(function () {
    origdata.push($(this).val());
});
```

and upon cancel, compare them to the current data fields.

```
var _isModalDirty=0;
$('.controls :input').each(function (i, item) {
    if(origdata[i]!=item.val())
       _isModalDirty++;
});
```

Your true/false test will still work, as 0 will return false, and any instances that do not match will increment and turn it boolean positive.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because is _isModalDirty initially undefined.  if I add a

```
var _isModalDirty = false;
```

to the top of your javascript then it works for me

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/8jxwg8ub/)

Edit: You might want to consider setting the state of the form as data on the form instead of a variable:

```
$('.controls :input').change(function (){
    console.log('change run');
    $(this).closest('.modal').data('isModalDirty', true);
});

$('.modal-cancel').click(function (){
    console.log('click run');
    if ( $(this).closest('.modal').data('isModalDirty') ) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel? You will lose your unsaved changes.')) {
            closeModalPopup();
        }
    } else {
        closeModalPopup();
    }
});

var closeModalPopup = function () {
    resetModalPopup();
    $('.modal').data('isModalDirty', false).modal('hide');
}

var resetModalPopup = function() {
    $('.controls :input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.val('');
    });    
}
```

This would make it easier to support several such modals on a page, as it is not using a global variable. [Fiddle using data](http://jsfiddle.net/adamconway/8jxwg8ub/2/)

**Edit 2**
The OP said in a comment that they still had to click twice.  I think the problem is actually the alerts you use for debugging.  If you enter text in one field then immediately click the cancel button the alert from the change event runs.  Alert is a blocking process and in that block the click event seems to get lost.  Try changing the `alert` to `console.log` (which is a much less annoying and less intrusive - both on the user and the functionality - way of debugging out data in my opinion) and I think it works (up to the undefined variable issue discussed above).

Comment: You are write that I missed out the initialisation in my fiddle. I have corrected that here; http://jsfiddle.net/arame3333/8jxwg8ub/1/

Comment: Having said that, if I enter data into the input box, I still have to click cancel twice to close the modal

Comment: I don't.  Not with the fixed version.  (Well, I have to click one then OK on the confirm but that is the idea isn't it?)  Actually, the only problem I had was the undefined variable if I tried to close the form before changing any fields.  What browser are you using? I have only tested in Fiefox.  That said, I would not have expected any browser to have an issue with this.

Comment: I think the problem is your alerts.  See my second edit

Comment: I am using ie9. Yes you are right that removing the alerts and replacing with the console.log has made the difference and it works in jsFiddle. For some reason it does not always work with jsFiddle, sometimes the clicks on the links do not work. However I need to find out what is wrong with the original code.

Comment: Console log is a smart idea I had not come across before, thank you for that!